# Java app on OS X: Where is the version in default About dialog taken from?

Tags: java, macos, jar, executable-jar

I have made a small Java .jar GUI application. When I run it on OS X, the default system menu About dialog says something like MyApp version 1.0 (1.0). Where is that version number taken from? I would like to change it to match with the version of my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a real MacOS X application. The version will then come from Info.plist (key: CFBundleVersion). I don't think you could change the version number in the default about dialog with a .jar. Another way to do it would be to create your own custom about dialog (with Apple's Java API).